# Angular update ng-model without quotations marks

Tags: angularjs, ngmodel

Here is my code : 
JS:

```
 $scope.gamma = {
        0 : 2
    };
    $scope.matrix = {
        1 : 21, 2 : 25, 3 : 21, 4 : 85, 5 : 798, 6 : 4, 7 : 51, 8 : 224, 9 : 63
    };
    $scope.update_layers = function(gamma, gvalue, matrix, mvalue){

        $scope.gamma = gamma;
         if(gvalue){
                $scope.gamma.gvalue = parseInt(gvalue)

                for(var i in $scope.gamma){
            $scope.gamma[i] = parseInt($scope.gamma[i]);
        }
        }

        if(mvalue){
                $scope.matrix.mvalue = parseInt(mvalue)
        }
```

HTML:

```
{{gamma}}{{matrix}}
                    <br />
               gamma : <span ng-repeat="(g, value) in gamma"> <input class="form-control" style="margin:5px;width:100px;text-align:center;display:inline-block;text-align:center"  ng-model="gamma[g]"></span>
                        <br />
               matrix : <span ng-repeat="(m, value) in matrix"> <input class="form-control" style="margin:5px;width:100px;text-align:center;display:inline-block;text-align:center"  ng-model="matrix[m]"></span>


                    <button class="btn" ng-click="update_layers(gamma, gamma.value, matrix, matrix.value)">update</button>
```

I want to show:
    `"1":21`   instead of   `"1":"21"`
Here my plnkr and my effors :
http://plnkr.co/edit/LFvqgeCtOWv4OGxiDDuY?p=preview

Comment: @RakeshBurbure Ok, but even when i console.log(gamma) there is ex. "1":"21", but i want "1":21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `type="number"` to your input fields. E.g.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" style="margin:5px;width:100px;text-align:center;display:inline-block;text-align:center" ng-model="matrix[m]">
```